# TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined Discord.js simple code

Tags: javascript, express, discord.js, bots

So, I am making a bot and here's a part of my code what has a problem:

```
    if(message.content.startsWith("$sudo make-mod ")) {
    target = message.mentions.users.first();
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id = "<@&938235657929773077>")

    console.log(target)
    target.roles.add(role.id)
}
```

and I get this error:

```
    target.roles.add(role.id)
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

I don't know what's the problem. Can someone help???

Comment: Update: I made target.roles.add(role.id) to target.roles.add(role)

Comment: You're using `console.log(target)`. What does it tell you? Does `target` have a `roles` property?

Comment: try `target = message.mentions.members.first();` since in guilds you can only mention members and not users

Answer (score 0):

When you use `message.mentions.users.first()`, it returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) which doesn't have a `roles` property. Instead, you need a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), which does have the `roles` property and you can fetch the `GuildMember` by using `message.mentions.members.first()`. You can also add an if check to see whether the mentioned user was valid or not by using this: `if (!target) return`

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on what you changed and why it is better?

Comment: I did that but it gives me this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mentions' of undefined

Comment: Try doing `console.log(message)` to see if the message is coming as undefined

Comment: It logs out a whole buncha stuff:

Comment: <ref *1> Message {
  channelId: '938522474834964521',
  guildId: '938225643127189514',
  id: '938819259386171392',
  createdTimestamp: 1643902353856,
  type: 'DEFAULT',
  system: false,
  content: '$sudo make-mod <@!928739338089537586>',
  author: User {
    id: '904448678532640798',
    bot: false,
    system: false,
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    username: 'awesomearjun',
    discriminator: '1177',
    avatar: '10612065736403d939b48950b27223c6',
    banner: undefined,
    accentColor: undefined
  },
  pinned: false,

Comment: and also more than that

Comment: The problem might be that there aren't any mentions in the message. Try mentioning anyone and then see

Comment: I was mentioning some @Caladan

Comment: *someone i ment

Comment: Can you show your current code right now? It would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to use members

```js
target = message.mentions.members.first()
```